# warning, KeyError on .loc

Tags: python, pandas

I used the .loc in this code and it works fine `win_data = df.loc[df['HOME_TEAM_WINS'] == 1]`  but when I use it `win_data['SMA5'] = win_data.loc['PTS_home'].rolling(5).mean()`   I get KeyError! if I don't put the .loc it works fine but I get the warning! Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) wants the first index to be the *row* index. When you do `win_data["PTS_home"]`, you get the `"PTS_home"` column of the dataframe. The equivalent `.loc` syntax would be `win_data.loc[:, "PTS_home"]` (i.e. all rows, and `"PTS_home"` column)

`df.loc[df['HOME_TEAM_WINS'] == 1]` works because you're using. a different kind of indexing, viz. [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) to extract only those rows for which the `"HOME_TEAM_WINS"` column is `1`